# PDO: "Invalid parameter number" when substituting multiple parameters with same value

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

How do I bind my parameter if it appears multiple times in the query as follows?

```
$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE firstname LIKE :string OR lastname LIKE :string");

$STH->bindValue(':string', '%'.$string.'%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$result = $STH->execute();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You mentioned two parameters (with the same name) for the prepare statement, yet you supply a value for the first parameter only (that's what the error was about).

Not quite sure how PDO internally solved the same-parameter-name issue, but you can always avoid that.

Two possible solutions:

```
$sql = "select * from $table ".
       "where "
       "first_name like concat('%', :fname, '%') or ".
       "last_name  like concat('%', :lname, '%')";
$stmt= $DBH->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':fname', $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':lname', $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

```
$sql = "select * from $table ".
       "where "
       "first_name like concat('%', ?, '%') or ".
       "last_name  like concat('%', ?, '%')";
$stmt= $DBH->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $string, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

---

By the way, the existing way you have done still has SQL injection issues.

Comment: Thx ajreal, why is my way still injection sensitive?

Comment: because you included everything into the full sql, while you should bind the exact value to be searched only, like the example

Comment: @ajreal: just some small thing: you are missing a . (dot) between `"where "` and `"first_name..."`

Comment: This problem exists *only when using native prepared statements*, PDO emulated ones can handle case with name multiple times. To enable or disable native statements, one can use `$PDO->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false)`.

Comment: @Ciantic Thanks for that extra bit of information, I had just switched to native prepared statements when I encountered this :)

Comment: I think at this point, PDO is ugly to use. its cubersome to bind the same para with different name repeatly.