# Use SET @variable=? inside of mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

i have a query that uses a few variables in mysql. The query looks something like this:

```
SET @var1 = 1;
SET @var2 = 2;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column1=@var1 
AND table.column2=@var2
AND table.colum3=@var1 * @var2;
```

I would like to make a prepared statement like:

```
$sql=' SET @var1 = ?;
SET @var2 = ?;
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column1=@var1 
AND table.column2=@var2
AND table.colum3=@var1 * @var2;'
```

and then just bind two params to it. But this gives me an mysql sytax error near the SET @var1=?;

Of course, in the example, I could bind three variables and do the calculations before querying. In my real query there are more advanced calculations and I would need to bind the same variable to multiple places. And that seems like repeating and bad coding practice.

Any solutions for this?

Comment: You cant parameterize parts of the query (sql, db name, table name, column name, etc), only data.

Comment: But those variables concerns data.

Comment: I misread the question. *doh*

Comment: No problems. We all do such things.

Comment: Use prepared statements, please.

Comment: In what way is that not a prepared statement? The entire question is on how to make this work smooth in a prepared statement. If you have a different solution, please share it.

Comment: Isn't the error message complaining about running more than one SQL statement in a single query? Does your DB library support that?

Comment: Álvaro: It might be so. Could I make this as one statement?

Answer (score 1):

PHP offers prepared statements and parametrized queries out of the box, you can just use them.

```
$var1 = 1;
$var2 = 2;

$connection = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column1=:var1 AND table.column2=:var2 AND table.colum3=:varSum';
$statement = $connection->prepare($sql);

$statement->bindValue(':var1', $var1, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':var2', $var2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(':varSum', $var1 + $var2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->execute();
```

This code is just an example, it is not tested.

Comment: I might have been forming my question badly, but this is what I want to avoid. In this example I still bind to three places from php, var1, var2 and varSum. Since my real query contains the same two values to multiple places I would need to bind about 8 variables that contains only 2 values. And thats what I want to bypass by using the mysql variables insted. It makes the code much easier to maintain.

Comment: It seems to be a limitation of _native_ prepared statements, _emulated_ prepared statements [seem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4710370/575765) to be able to insert the same value multiple times (never tested this myself, maybe it's version dependend too). Though, in the example above you actually have 2 variables, you only have to call `bindValue()` multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution: feed your values in to a subquery, then you can reference them from there:

```php
function GetStuffFromTable(mysqli $db, int $column1, int $column2): array
{
    $sql = ' 
        SELECT * 
        FROM (SELECT ? var1, ? var2) vars
        INNER JOIN table 
        ON table.column1 = vars.var1 
        AND table.column2 = vars.var2
        AND table.column3 = vars.var1 * vars.var2;
    ';
    $statement = $db->prepare($sql);
    try
    {
        $statement->bind_param("ii", $column1, $column2);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        return $statement->fetch_all($result);
    } finally {
        $statement->close();
    }
}
```

Note: I came here looking for an answer to the same question / I don't know PHP well, so can't comment on the quality of this solution from a PHP perspective.

Answer (score -1):

you should use multi_query

```
    <?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "username";
    $password = "password";
    $dbname = "myDB";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql=' SET @var1 = '.$v1.';
    SET @var2 = '.$v2.';
    SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.column1=@var1 
    AND table.column2=@var2
    AND table.colum3=@var1 * @var2;'

    if ($conn->multi_query($sql) === TRUE) {
        echo "New records created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }

    $conn->close();
    ?>
```