# PDO statement doesn't work with LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

There is a problem in my statement. I believe it's from the LIKE, since if I remove it, it works well. This is what I've finally got, but it still doesn't fetch any results:

```
$search = '%' . $_POST['search'] . '%';

switch($_POST['sortby']) {
    case 'new':
        $sortby = 'code DESC';
        break;
    case 'popular':
        $sortby = 'RAND()';
        break;
    case 'cheap':
        $sortby = 'price ASC';
        break;
    case 'expensive':
        $sortby = 'price DESC';
        break;
    default:
        $sortby = 'code DESC';
        break;
}

$start = $_POST['start'];

$end = $_POST['end'];

$STH = $DBH->prepare("SELECT id, code, name, oldprice, price, date, status FROM products_retail WHERE (code LIKE :search OR name LIKE :search) AND status<>0 ORDER BY $sortby LIMIT :start, :end");

$STH->bindParam(':search', $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$STH->bindParam(':start', $start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$STH->bindParam(':end', $end, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$STH->execute();
```

Any help is appriciated.

[EDIT] This is the error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number' in ...
```

Comment: Could you show us the error?

Comment: You can't use placeholder with same name more than once. Period.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO: "Invalid parameter number" when substituting multiple parameters with same value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710169/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-when-substituting-multiple-parameters-with-same)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two parameters (with the same name) :search in your query. Try to look on this solution:

[PDO: "Invalid parameter number" when substituting multiple parameters with same value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710169/pdo-invalid-parameter-number-when-substituting-multiple-parameters-with-same)